# How "Sensitive" Are Latitudes and Longitudes?

Tags: geometry

Generally, we are told that just because a measurement (e.g. distance, weight, etc.) has many  many numbers on the right side of the decimal point, does not necessarily mean that these measurements are more precise.

For example, I might have a balance that can only weigh objects up to 2 decimal points. "Object A" might weigh 92.12 Kilograms and "Object B" might weigh 39.82 Kilograms. If were to divide these numbers, I might (naively) conclude that : "Object A" is 2.31341 times more heavier than "Object B" - but to believe that my measurement has such a level of precision would be misleading, seeing as the balance can only weigh objects up to 2 decimal points.

The same way, I was looking at latitudes and longitudes. For example (I specifically chose 2 places that are really close to each other), the following measurements are from Google Earth:

- Madison Square Garden (New York) is located at : 40.75087428987512, -73.99334214190007
- Empire State Building (New York) is located at 40.74908160188187, -73.98523605485785

[image]

Suppose I want to find out the distance between these two places - there exists a formula called the Haversine Distance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) that is meant for calculating the distance between two sets of latitudes and longitudes.

Calculation 1: If I were to calculate the Haversine Distance between these two places using all numbers to the right of the decimal point (https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), I get the following distance: 0.7113 Kilometers

[image]

Calculation 2: If I repeat the same calculation using only 1 decimal point (40.7, -73.9) and (40.7, -73.9) -  I naturally get a distance of 0 Kilometers:

[image]

Calculation 3: If I repeat the same calculation using only 2 decimal points (40.75, - 73.99) and (40.74, -73.98) - I get a distance of 1.395 Kilometers:

[image]

- All this being said, does this mean that humans have figured out how to measure Latitude and Longitude to such a high level of precision?
- If we are interested in calculating the distance between 2 pairs of Latitudes and Longitudes - how many decimal points are we required to use to obtain a "realistic distance" between 2 pairs of points (e.g. 0.7113 Kilometers vs. 1.395 Kilometers - which is "more" correct?)?
- On the above map, it indicates that the "walking distance" between these two places is 0.4 Miles (0.64 Kilometers) - however, the Haversine Distance appears to be 0.7113 Kilometers. Is this because the "walking path" that Google Maps identified probably does not correspond to the "purely spherical path" corresponding to the Haversine Distance?

Thank you!

Comment: [GPS](https://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/) can achieve a precision of a few meters. In comparison, one arcsecond of longitude at the equator is roughly 30m. However, it does not mean one can get such a precision in all circumstances: when using the haversine formula to compute the great circle distance, you are assuming that the earth is a sphere, while it's actually more like an ellipsoid (and not a perfect ellipsoid). This has an impact on accuracy of computations.

Comment: Object A weighs 92.12 ±.005 kg.
Object B weighs 39.82 ±.005 kg.
¶
Their ratios can be anywhere between:
92.115 ÷ 39.825 = 2.312994350282485
92.125 ÷ 39.815 = 2.313826447318849
¶
That is the true value is 2.313410398800667 ± .000416048518182, which like the original numbers has only 4 significant digits.

Comment: As @Jean-ClaudeArbaut said, GPS is amazingly accurate. I have not studied in detail (or throroughly fact checked) but once read the following : 1. there are GPS type systems which are even more accurate (though not publicly accessible) which can be used in engineering to build bridges for example within a precision of cm. 2. What makes GPS so accurate is that they do their calculations using special (probably even general) theory of relativity to account for effects of the large speeds at which the satellites fly in the orbit.

Comment: If you want to know how sensitive the distance is to variation in the longitudes and latitudes of the points, you might be interested in reading about [propagation of uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty).

Comment: I would argue that your question is not really about mathematics, but about geodesy. Maybe your question will attract better comments and answers if you post it in a geodesy forum.